# Move Domino mailfiles to a new directory location on server

Tags: lotus-domino

Currently we have a lot of mailfiles in different directories on the same server, some are located on the server in data\mail and others are located in data\mail\DK... or data\mail\USA...

These mailfiles are also replicated to other servers and we have noticed on the other servers the mailfiles have another file structure.

This makes administration very difficult so we would like to move all our maiLfiles to the data\mail... directories on all servers.

(Some clients have local replicas)

What is the best practise for doing this?

can the admin process do this, move the file, update person record and update clients?

Comment: Might be better to ask this on serverfault.com. The admin version of this site.

Answer (score 1):

AdminPs "Move to Another Server" functionality works fine for that job (watch out for the delete requests, though).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the original administrator set up the system so that the users mailfile on the home mail server is in the root of the \mail directory and that the sub directories contain replicas of mailfiles from others servers as a means of cheap backup.

I'd suggest looking at the NAb and seeing if this is indeed the case and if it is then you are in luck. All you will need to do in this case is bring the server down, move all the mailfiles in the subdirectories into the main mail directory and restart the server. Once the server comes back up it will continue to replicate these mailfiles with the other server.

I would check the replication connection documents to see if any special replication schedules have been setup for those subdirectories, if so you'll have to adjust them to ensure proper replication.

If the users home mailserver is not using the root mail directory as their mailfile storage area then it is a longer process. You can use AdminP to do it but it COULD cause you issues if you accidently come back in at a later date and approve the deletion requests or if the server doesn't have enough diskspace to double all the mailfiles, also having two replicas of a mailfile on a single server is not a good idea either.

If you need to do the long process I'd look at doing it manually. Down the server, move the mailfiles, bring the server up and edit each person doc to set the correct location for the mailfile and then visit each user machine to edit their location document to point to correct location. It is the only safe way to do it.

The last option is to buy a new server and then use adminp to move all the users to that server, making sure the mailfiles is stored in the /mail directory, no risk of duplicate replicas on a single server, adminP looks after adjusting the settings on all the users machines and you end up with a nice clean, new server ( on which you could implement things like transaction logs and daos )

Answer (score -1):

As for the safe way to go on this one:

Correcting the physical mailfile location should be quite easy (bring server down, move mailfiles, start server again), but modifying all those person documents could be quite complicated if you go one by one.

I would encourage you to use Ytria's ScanEZ software, so that you can mass-modify all person docs in the NAB using a simple Replace Substring formula to correct the Mailfile path information at once. 
This is an incredibly fast process, should not take more than 10-20 seconds to go.

Comment: Ben: You should disclose the fact that you work for Ytria.

And suggesting your product for a case where a very simple Lotus formula agent would suffice is really, really bad form.

Comment: He did disclose the fact he worked for Ytria, but was removed as you are not supposed to put contact information into responses. It is also mentioned in his profile page.